# Responsive Bootstrap Tiles (News Like Layout)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have been stuck trying to obtain a particular layout with bootstrap finding little success.

```
 .row
  .col-md-8
    %h3 Title
    %p Description
  .col-md-4
    .row
      .col-md-12
        %p Side Item 1
      .col-md-12
        %p Side Item 2
```

[Drawing of attempted Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/390hS.jpg)

Some of the key issues I am having is getting the even spacing between the squares while still having everything line up in a clean fashion.

I also have no idea how to get the two elements on the right to "unstack" when viewed on a smaller screen.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nested](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) `columns` for the layout. To acheive equal height is another story and probably depends (somewhat) on what are going inside those divs.

```css
/**CSS For Display Purposes Only**/

body,
html {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.alert.alert-top {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.alert.alert-bottom {
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info alert-top">Top</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
          <div class="alert alert-success alert-bottom">Bottom Left</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
          <div class="alert alert-warning alert-bottom">Bottom Right</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```